# NO miner module in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, geth-debugging

I am new to ethereum. I installed mist on Mac（10.13.5）, but did not "brew install ethereum". When try run ">geth attach" in Terminal, it does not show "miner" module. Below is what the screen shows "Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

`instance: Geth/v1.8.8-stable-2688dab4/darwin-amd64/go1.10.1 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0".`

Could anyone please let me know what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like `miner module` in geth.

When you start up your ethereum node with geth it is not mining by default. To start it in mining mode, you use the [`--mine`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) command line option. The [`--minerthreads`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) parameter can be used to set the number parallel mining threads (defaulting to the total number of processor cores).

```
geth --mine --minerthreads=4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it does mine using the above command line. What i am asking is, in the geth console, when i run "miner.start()", it shows "
ReferenceError: 'miner' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1" . do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are starting ***geth*** initially, but if you include ***miner*** in the ***rpcapi*** like below it should work fine.

`$geth --datadir=./chaindata/ --ipcpath $HOME/.ethereum/geth.ipc --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner`

Answer (score 0):

You need to stipulate the miner module in the --http.api or --ws.api flags like below.

```
--http.api=eth,net,web3,miner
```